# Scipy Sparse: Singular Matrix Warning after SciPy/NumPy Update

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-equation

my problem results from nodal analysis for a large system of resistors. I am basically setting up a large sparse matrix *A*, my solution vector *b*, and I'm trying to solve the linear equation *A* * *x* = *b*.
In order to do so, I'm using the **scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve** method.

Until recently, everything worked fine until I upgraded SciPy from v0.13.3 to v0.19.1 (which also included a NumPy Upgrade to v1.13.1). I'm running Python 2.7.6. When using the same code as before the update, I get errors, especially for systems that produce `matrices > 10000 x 10000` .
The warnings are:

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
  warn("Matrix is exactly singular", MatrixRankWarning)
```

**spsolve** is then - sometimes - unable to find a solution.

As I am performing nodal analysis, a singular matrix is expected since the position of the ground potential is generally not well-defined. However, before the update, a solution was found in 99% of the cases, maybe more. Now, I'm at 10% for large systems at best. I have not changed the algorithm and for a few tests, I have used identical code as before. Here is how I set up my calculation:

1. I generate a random three-dimensional network of resistors (I realize that I could accidentally create unsolvable networks but the percentages above should not change that drastically). The only SciPy/NumPy functions used here is np.random
2. I create a sparse lil-matrix which I fill with conductance values extracted from my resistor network. I also create a solution vector which is not sparse.
3. I convert the conductance matrix to csr-format and use the **spsolve** method. This is where my code lately fails.

Could it be the method that has changed?

Is **spsolve** maybe even inappropriate? The matrices I create are generally symmetric and in a block tridiagonal form. Is there a more efficient way to solve the linear equation than **spsolve**?

Every sort of help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading.

[Here is how my matrices look like in 'spy'-representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m88y5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous scipy-version is quite old and it used [umfpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMFPACK) for this task.

**Due to licensing-issues** (GPL is not compatible with scipy and i think umfpack switched the license at some point), **this lib was removed** and now [superlu](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/) is used. Many people observed slow-downs (and robustness issues), but evaluating performance might not be that easy (superlu can be fast and robust too).

Read also [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3831#issuecomment-50230520).

You probably got two options:

- Tune superlu's parameters (read the official superlu documentation and scipy's docs on how to pass these options)

  - Pivoting and Ordering is very important!
  - There is also a *symmetric-mode* (not really a highly-tuned symmetric-matrix solver, but possibly better pivoting-rules)
  - Maybe iterative-refinement can help too (unsure!)
- If the license-stuff is not a problem for you: use [scikit-umfpack](https://github.com/scikit-umfpack/scikit-umfpack) to make scipy use umfpack again!

If your matrix is PSD, [cholmod](https://developer.nvidia.com/cholmod), available within [scikit-sparse](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse) (currently unmaintained!) might be the lib to use (again: license)!

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, that sounds reasonable. I will discuss with my sys admin on monday. 
What is your take on 'minres' as a direct solver? Since my matrix is symmetric, I consider it a viable alternative. I know, in the doc it says that the function is experimental and subject to change but it works fine with my code. For large systems, it is even faster than spsolve and the results agrees within 99.9%. Plus, it definitely yields a result.